# Running Salamander as admin on a per operation basis

Tags: windows-7, security, windows-explorer, uac

Is there a way of running Altap Salamander at the same security level as windows explorer?  In windows explorer, if you attempt to, say, delete a file in Program Files it will pop up saying that you need admin privileges to do that, and you can continue, skip, or cancel.  If you try to delete the same file in salamander, you will be stopped from deleting the file, but you can't click on an option to temporary grant it admin privileges.

You could alter the compatibility settings to have it always run as admin, but that doesn't ask at all if you were to attempt to delete the file.

I want to use it as a normal user most of the time, but not have to re-run it as admin if there is only one thing that needs changing; like how you normally are a user in linux and only call sudo when you need it, you don't run as root most of the time.

I found this
http://forum.altap.cz/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3403
but it dosen't offer a solution to the problem, I was hoping you guys would know something more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Altap Salamander does not yet support UAC. To delete, e.g., system files, right click the Altap Salamander icon and select "Run as administrator", perform the operation and exit.

BTW, for older Windows versions like Windows XP I can recommend to install [SuRun](http://kay-bruns.de/wp/software/surun/). Then one also can work as normal user and enter the own credentials to do some administrator work.